# What is the difference between "de sitôt" and "de si tôt"?

Tags: expressions, adverbes, indications-de-temps

> Si elle s’est bien remise de son récent traumatisme, elle ne compte pas pour autant y remettre les pieds **de si tôt**.

I always spell and treat "sitôt" as a single word myself, but I wonder what is the difference between the two? A regional difference or something, perhaps?

> Si elle s’est bien remise de son récent traumatisme, elle ne compte pas pour autant y remettre les pieds **de sitôt**.

Comment: Where did you read this sentence?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez likely in [Paris-Match](https://parismatch.be/actualites/people/48853/kim-kardashian-france-10-ans)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first form is incorrect.

While both *sitôt* and *si tôt* are possible in French, they are never interchangeable. *[Sitôt](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sit%C3%B4t)* is equivalent to *aussitôt* ("straight after, as soon as") and also used in the set expression *pas de sitôt* which means "not before a long time". On the other hand, *[si](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/si/1) [tôt](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/t%C3%B4t)* simply mans "so early".

At least for native speakers, a simple method to sort out which one to use is to replace *tôt* by *tard* and see if the resulting sentence works.

*Elle n'y remettra pas les pieds de ***si tard*** is impossible so the right form is: *elle n'y remettra pas les pieds de **sitôt***.

*Elle y a remis les pieds **si tard** qu'il n'y avait plus personne* is possible so the right form is: *elle y a remis les pieds **si tôt** qu'il n'y avait plus personne*

See the *[OQLF: Sitôt et si tôt](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2364)*